# Smoothscroll can't get tab active on click

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I found several solutions for my problem but I can't get anyone to work. I'm trying to smooth scroll to a tab when a link is clicked. That works perfectly. The problem is that when I have multiple links on a page that points to to a tab, only the link works which have a tab active. So when I click a link and that tab isn't active the link doesn't work.

So what I try to do is to make a tab active when I click a link.

What I have:

```
<a class="goSmoothly" href="#" data-target="description" onclick="return false">Link to tab1</a>
<a class="goSmoothly" href="#" data-target="specs" onclick="return false">Link to tab2</a>

<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#description" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#specs" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>


$( '.goSmoothly' ).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + $(this).data('target');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 150)
    }, 1200);

    var self = $(this), className = "active";
    self.addClass(className).siblings("."+className).removeClass(className);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
var target = "#" + $(this).data('target');

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 150)
}, 1200);
```

Your `$(target)` selector is selecting an element with the `id` attribute of either *description* or *specs*, however in your code you have no elements with those IDs. Instead you have elements with those `href` attributes, which you can select instead using:

```
var target = $(this).data('target');

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: ($('[href="' + target + '"]').offset().top - 150)
}, 1200);
```

Also rather than calling:

```
self.addClass(className).siblings("."+className).removeClass(className);
```

You can simply:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Ok thx that works and thx for your clear explaination! Only one last thing. The 'addClass' doesn't add class active to the closest li element. Any thoughts on that? Closest doesn't work.

Comment: One last thing. I get an "TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined" when I click the link. Happens when I change "#" + $(this).data('target'); to $(this).data('target');